# Finding two words within same paragraph in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am looking for a way to find two words within same paragraph in elascticsearch. I looked at the documentation and found out that the words are stored in a key value mechanism where key being the word and value being the document number(with indices). I really doubt that '\n' will be stored in elasticsearch indexing. if it does i could try using the span within query but i am not sure about it. Can someone give directions to get around this.

Comment: How do you index your text? One page per document, one paragraph per document, one sentence?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Right now i have not made any changes to indexing. i am just loading my data stored in csv file using logstash. i guess that might be using default settings

Comment: Hm. You need to know a bit more about how you are doing this. And to understand some basics about Elasticsearch. Otherwise, it's too much to ask in a stackoverflow post, imo.

Comment: @AndreiStefan actually I am using elasticsearch for first time, if you could provide the link to the elasticsearch documentation regarding the thing you are talking about or even the name of the topic. I would read the documentation and let you know,what i am actually doing.

Comment: It's not a specific thing. You are lacking the basics. Start with this, from the beginning: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/index.html